# Adding background mode on Capabilities tabs

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, background

I am using Xcode 6.3 and I just added bluetooth background mode on the capability tab:

[image]

There is a step required that says "Add the 'Required Background Modes" keys to your info.plist file.

However apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) says that this is added automatically (see below) and if I check my info.plist file I find the following:

> Declaring Your App’s Supported Background Tasks Support for some types
>   of background execution must be declared in advance by the app that
>   uses them. In Xcode 5 and later, you declare the background modes your
>   app supports from the Capabilities tab of your project settings.
>   Enabling the Background Modes option adds the UIBackgroundModes key to
>   your app’s Info.plist file. Selecting one or more checkboxes adds the
>   corresponding background mode values to that key. Table 3-1 lists the
>   background modes you can specify and the values that Xcode assigns to
>   the UIBackgroundModes key in your app’s Info.plist file.

[image]

**Is this enough?**

How can I test if it works correctly?

Comment: i think following link will help you.some once also face same problem as you faced. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28740459/transferring-data-from-central-to-peripheral-in-background-mode-in-ios/29674995#29674995

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is enough. The UI is taking the values directly from the plist and writing them there.

You can open the plist manually and see what is written there to make sure. It's just a text file.

Comment: If I am using some third party manager to connect to BLE devices, do I need to add some code support to enable the background mode there? E.g. http://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/Bluno_SKU:DFR0267

Answer (score 1):

If you change anything from Capabilities then you would see that your plist would get *automatically* updated based from Capabilities. They are both basically the same:

[image]
 <sub>to see the text, click on the image to have it enlarged</sub>

That which you see there is Xcode's convenience...telling you hey I wrote this in the plist for you . Previously there was no such convenience and you had to go into plist and type it in *manually*.